# Fonte demora a carregar no site hospedado

Tags: css

Eu fui hospedar meu site e eu uso `@font-face` no CSS, ele apresenta uma lentidão enorme para carregar essa fonte no site. O que eu posso fazer?

Answer (score 4):

Steve Sauders fez [um artigo sobre este tema](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/10/13/font-face-and-performance/), porém está em inglês, caso você entenda vale a pena conferir.

Resumindo:

1. Só use `@font-face` se você realmente precisar usar.
2. Coloque a sua declaração `@font-face` acima de todas as tags SCRIPT.
3. Não inclua declarações não utilizadas do `@font-face` - o IE irá
   baixá-las se elas são usadas ou não.

Talvez isto te ajude.